# Select Distinct Column values using JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to hibernate and spring Technologies, How can select distinct column values from table, This is code,

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
{
this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
Public List<String> getidList()
{
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT surveyId from DATATABLE";

return list;
}
```

How can I write my sql query in JdbcTemplate. Which method of JdbcTemplate should use now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT DISTINCT surveyId from DATATABLE", Long.class);
```

Comment: What does the Long.class means ?

Comment: @user3300593: it's explained in the doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

Comment: `queryForList` says that it returns a `List` of values from single column. Since `List` is generic class the second argument of this method is a type of list elements. I decide to mark it as `Long`, becuase your column is `surveyId`. Typically ids are numbers. Of course, you can say `String.class`

Comment: I got the sql exception that, Invalid value for getLong - 'Ganga-1', My table column data type is varchar